# On the probability of getting the same number for three dice

Tags: probability, dice

I found the probability of having the same number when throwing 3 dice to be $1\times\left(\frac16\right)^2$.

In addition, I don't understand how do people get the equation $\left(\frac16\right)^3\times6=\frac1{36}$, like why do we have to multiply $\left(\frac16\right)^3$ by six?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a small supplement to the nice answers addressing your question, since I didn't found it mentioned explicitly.

> We can calculate the *probability* of an event by calculating the ratio of the number of *favorable choices* or number of *successes* of an event with the number of *all choices* of an event.
>
> This way we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{\text{number of successes}}{\text{number of all choices}}=\frac{6}{6^3}=\frac{1}{6^2}=\frac{1}{36}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Can you help me understand why the answer is not B(3; 3, 1/6) = 0.46%?

Answer (score 32):

The probability that the first die is a 1 is $\frac16$. The probability that the second die is a 1 is $\frac16$. The probability that the third die is a 1 is $\frac16$. Multiplying this together gives $\frac1{6^3}$ for the probability that 
all dice are a 1.

We have the same chance $\left(\frac1{6^3}\right)$ of rolling three 2s, three 3s, three 4s, three 5s, or three 6s, so the probability of rolling any number on all three dice at the same time is $6\cdot\frac{1}{6^3}$, or $\frac1{36}$.

Also note that both your answer $\frac{1}{6^2}$ and $6\cdot\frac{1}{6^3}$ are equal to $\frac1{36}$.

Answer (score 13):

By counting:
There are $6^3$ possible outcomes: 1-1-1, 1-1-2, ..., 6-6-5, 6-6-6. There are $6$ outcomes with all the numbers the same: 1-1-1, 2-2-2, ..., 5-5-5, 6-6-6. So the probability of all the numbers being the same is $6/6^3$.

Alternatively:
Throw the first die. It doesn't matter what number you get.

Throw the second die. The probability of getting the same number is $1/6$.

Throw the third die. The probability of getting the same number is again $1/6$.

So the probability of three numbers the same is $1/6 \times 1/6$.

Comment: FYI: you can use `$\frac{num}{den}$` to render a fraction vertically.

Answer (score 5):

Are you're asking for the probability of all three dice having the same number, regardless of which number it is?

Imagine rolling the dice one at a time.  We don't care which number we see, so we don't care about the outcome of the roll of the first die; it just tells us what we're looking for.

Whatever that number is, the chances that the second die comes up on it is $\frac16$.

The chances that the third die comes up with it is also $\frac16$.

So the chances that *both* the second and third dice come up with the same number that's on the first is $\frac16$ × $\frac16$ = $\frac1{36}$.